# nHibernate: Subqueries.WhereIn

Tags: c#, nhibernate

So I am trying to create a query, which limits the number of results with a subquery.

```
Select * From Products Where products.supplierid IN (Select supplierid FROM supplier WHERE active = 1)
```

Since I use multiple subquery where conditions, I first tried to do something like this:

```
mainQuery.And(
   Restrictions.Disjunction()
   .Add(Subqueries.WhereExists(subqueryFilterA))
   .Add(Subqueries.WhereExists(subqueryFilterB))
);
```

This works fine, except I do not want a `WhereExists` but a `WhereIn`. But `WhereIn` does not seem to exist.

The only workaround I found is:

```
mainQuery.Where(
   Restrictions.Disjunction()
   .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("products.supplierId", subqueryFilterA))
);
```

This seems to work alright. But since the subqueryFilterA is now a `DetachedCriteria` I can no longer use linq.

Is there a reason why there is no `Subqueries.WhereIn`?

Comment: `I can no longer use linq.` Why? There is `DetachedCriteria` property in `QueryOver` subquery. `QueryOver.Of<T>().Where(...).Select(...).DetachedCritera`

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Yes that would would work, but I still have to use `Subqueries.PropertyIn("products.supplierId", QueryOver.Of<T>().Where(...).Select(...).DetachedCritera)`. I cant lose the `"products.supplierId"` and change it to something like this:  `PropertyIn(() => productsDto.Supplyer, QueryOver.Of<T>().Where(...).Select(...).DetachedCritera)`, or am I wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Subqueries.WhereProperty`:

```
Subqueries
  .WhereProperty(() => products.supplierId)
  .In(QueryOver.Of<T>.Where(...).Select(...))
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought this would exand in something like `IN (@p1, @p2, @p3, ...)` which would have limited the number of ids one could have.. but I was wrong.